# More Global Spares or dedicated spares

Tags: raid, storage, hp

I have 74 x 300GB disk on a HP MSA2324sa.
The magic for me is 3 x RAID10 vDisks of 16 drives each. And then 2 x RAID50 vDisks of 10 drives each. That leaves me 6 drives. I could assign 5 dedicated spares and 1 Global or 6 Global spares.

What would be best? The Globals can be used on any of the 73 other drives as its 3 enclosures connected to same 2 controllers. So its one domain covering 74 drives.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geez. That's a lot of disks on an old SAN.

Either way...

- Can you elaborate on how your shelves are connected?
- Are these D2700 or MSA70?
- Did you use dual-path SAS cabling?
- Are your disks all dual-port drives?

If you have a full-mess SAS topology and aren't daisy-chaining your expansion shelves, use global spares. If you're daisy-chaining, use local spares.

Comment: Well its just 24 disks on the actuel P2000 and then 2 x 25 disks on two msa70. It is dual path and not daysichained. I can withstand controller and shelf downtime. The rest will continue. Edit: All disks are dual port 3g bit 300 GB 10 sas.

Comment: Use global spares. But also plan to upgrade. That equipment is really old and way end-of-life :)

Comment: You are correct its not new. However, its still 22TB RAW and 10.000 IOPS and HP still sells us Carepack so its fine for my VMware. We a 3PAR with SAS/SSD for our SQL servers so its not sharing with our VMware environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any reason not to use global spares.